# NodeJS mongoose - copy entire collection to database in another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

I'm trying to move my database to another server.

I have collection with 410k~ documents, I want to move them partially 100 by 100 to my new server with mongodb database.

There is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var itemdataModel = require('./model/ItemData');


mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('MongoDB Connection Error.' + err);
  process.exit(1);
});

mongoose.connection.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed');
  process.exit(1);
});

const ins = async (itemz) => {
  try {
    console.log("Inserting..")
    await mongoose.connect('<url to new database>', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    await gamedataModel.insertMany(itemz,
    async (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Insert query error" + err)
        await mongoose.connection.close()
      } else {
        console.log("Inserted!");
        await mongoose.connection.close()
      }

    });


  } catch (e) {
    console.log('insert error ' + e)
  }
}

(async () => {

  mongoose.connect('<url to old database>', { useNewUrlParser: true });
  const wyn = await itemdataModel.find({}).countDocuments()
  console.log('Documents count: ' + wyn)

  for (let i = 0; i < wyn; i += 100) {

    const docs = await itemdataModel.find({status: 'processed'}, '', {'skip': i, 'limit': 100 }).lean().exec()
    console.log('Selected ' + docs.length + ' documents to move')
    await mongoose.connection.close()
    await ins(docs)

  }


})();
```

There is problem with connecting to second database in "ins" function, there is my console output:

> Documents count: 411975
>
> Selected 100 docs to move
>
> Connection closed

How to get it working ? 
It is required to close first connection before starting another to insert 100 documents, then close it and back to my loop to move another 100 docs?

I do not want to overload the servers by opening 411k/100 connections at once on both of them

Answer (score 0):

I would not use nodejs for this task. Mongodb comes with utilities for backing up and restoring which will almost certainly do it better and more efficiently than you can, especially if you're adding the mongoose overhead.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/

Comment: NodeJS is my only possible way to do that

Comment: @KrystianK how so?  If you have access to the MongoDB servers from Node, you will have access to it through the backup and restore tools.

Comment: Thanks for this option, but it's still about nodejs way

Comment: @KrystianK maybe if you explain why that's the case, it might help inform the best answer.